# Table auto-adjust to table

Tags: tables

I have always had this problem when using LaTeX, but I have no idea how to make tables properly fit the table. It would be nice to do it automatically.

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline
\textbf{Study name}                                                                                                             & \textbf{Cohort dimension} & \textbf{Time before AF onset} & \textbf{ECG features}                                                                                                                                                                                       & \textbf{Used metric}                                    & \textbf{Model (accuracy)}                                                                           \\ \hline
Study on P-wave feature Time Course as Early Prediction of Paroxysmal AF                                                        & 24 patients               & 2h                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}- P-wave durations\\ - PR interval\\ - Heart rate\end{tabular}                                                                                                                   & Linear regression slope of the variability              & Linear discriminant (90.79\%)                                                                       \\
Morphological Variability of the P-wave for Premature Envision of Paroxysmal AF Events                                          & 46 patients + 53 controls & 2h                            & - P-wave area, energy, conduction velocity, dispersion, arc-length                                                                                                                                          & Linear regression slope of the variability              & Decision tree (86.33\%)                                                                             \\
Gaussian modelling of the P-wave morphology time course applied to anticipate paroxysmal atrial fibrillation                    & 46 patients + 53 controls & 2h                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}- Gaussian fit parameters\\ - Error between fitted Gaussian and P-wave\end{tabular}                                                                                              & Linear regression slope of the variability              & Stepwise discriminant analysis (86.69\%)                                                            \\
ECG-based Prediction of Atrial Fibrillation Development Following CABG                                                          & 14 patients + 36 controls & 48h                           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}- P-wave durations\\ - PQ interval\\ - Heart rate\\ - PQ segment, and P, Q, R, and S amplitudes\\ - Wavelet energies and entropy\end{tabular}                                    & Cumulative rank with statistically significant features & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Decision tree {[}applied over the time-course{]}\\ (85.3\%)\end{tabular} \\
Multiparameter Prediction Model for AF after CABG                                                                               & 11 patients + 29 controls & 48h                           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}- P-wave duration, slopes, amplitude, area and energies\\ - P-wave wavelet entropy\\ - PQ and PR intervals\\ - Heart rate\end{tabular}                                           & ECG features                                            & Decision tree (85\%)                                                                                \\
Prediction of Paroxysmal AF Onset in Postoperative Patients using Neuro-Fuzzy Modelling                                         & 37 patients + 53 controls & 30m                           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}-Number of premature atrial complexes\\ - HRV: mean, SDRR, rMSSD, total power, LF/HF, entropy\\ - P-wave duration, amplitude, shape, inflection point, energy ratio\end{tabular} & ECG features                                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Neuro-fuzzy\\ (70\%)\end{tabular}                                        \\
Alteration of the P-wave non-linear dynamics near the onset of paroxysmal atrial fibrillation                                   & 46 patients               & 2h                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}- P-wave durations\\ - P-wave area, arc-length\end{tabular}                                                                                                                      & Central tendency measurement                            & Decision tree (90\%)                                                                                \\
Role of the P-wave high frequency energy and duration as nonivasive cardiovascular predictors of paroxysmal atrial fibrillation & 46 patients + 53 controls & 2h                            & - P-wave frequency energies                                                                                                                                                                                 & Linear regression slope of the variability              & Stepwise discriminant analysis (80\%)                                                               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

But just the 1st column occupies the entire page.

Is there any way to make the table automatically decide which column size to give the columns to make it fit? (and then adjust font size, I guess).

Best wishes,
Diogo

Comment: you have specified `l` columns (single line with no linebreaking) replace `l` by `p{2cm}`  or whatever width you want for paragraph columns

Comment: op tables has more issues than braking text in cell into more lines. since op is novice i would like to show him how to design his table.  therefore i suggest to reopen his question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your table has more problems than simple breaking text in cells into more line:

- your table is huge and without special efforts is not possible to fit on one page
- probably you should consider to rotate table in landscape orientation, if this is allowed
- your page layout is unknown, so i decide to define own and also to stick with portraid oriented table.
- in comparison to your table code i made the following changes:

  - use smaller font (`\footnotesize`)
  - use `\enumitem` for lists in the fourth column
  - use the `\thead` macro from the `makcell` package for column headers (and with this made some columns narrower)
  - deliberately determine ratios between column widths
  - instead of `\hline` i use rules provided by package `booktabs`
  - for more vertical space between rows is used `\addlinespa` from the `booktabs` package

    ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[htb]
    \footnotesize
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                      leftmargin=*,
                      before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                      after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
    }
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                >{\hsize=1.6\hsize}L
                >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                                   c L
                >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                 @{}}
        \toprule
    \thead[bl]{Study name}
        &   \thead[lb]{Cohort\\ dimension}
            &   \thead[lb]{Time before\\ AF onset}
                &   \thead[bl]{ECG\\ features}
                    &   \thead[lb]{Used metric}
                        &   \thead[lb]{Model\\ (accuracy)}            \\
        \midrule
    Study on P-wave feature Time Course as Early Prediction of Paroxysmal AF
        &   24 patients
            &   2h
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   P-wave durations\
                \item   PR interval
                \item   Heart rate
                    \end{itemize}                                                                                                                   &   Linear regression slope of the variability
                        &   Linear discriminant (\SI{90.79}{\%})                \\
        \addlinespace
    Morphological Variability of the P-wave for Premature Envision of Paroxysmal AF Events
        &   46 patients + 53 controls
            &   2h
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   P-wave area, energy, conduction velocity, dispersion, arc-length
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   Linear regression slope of the variability
                        &   Decision tree (\si{86.33}{\%})                      \\
        \addlinespace
    Gaussian modelling of the P-wave morphology time course applied to anticipate paroxysmal atrial fibrillation
            &   46 patients + 53 controls
                &   2h
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Gaussian fit parameters
                \item   Error between fitted Gaussian and P-wave
                        \end{itemize}
                        &   Linear regression slope of the variability
                            &   Stepwise discriminant analysis (\SI{86.69}{\%}) \\
        \addlinespace
    ECG-based Prediction of Atrial Fibrillation Development Following CABG
        &    14 patients + 36 controls
            &   48h
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   P-wave durations
                \item   PQ interval
                \item   Heart rate
                \item   PQ segment, and P, Q, R, and S amplitudes
                \item   Wavelet energies and entropy
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   Cumulative rank with statistically significant features
                        &   Decision tree [applied over the time-course] (\SI{85.3}{\%}) \\
        \addlinespace
    Multiparameter Prediction Model for AF after CABG
        &   11 patients + 29 controls
            &   48h
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   P-wave duration, slopes, amplitude, area and energies
                \item   P-wave wavelet entropy
                \item   PQ and PR intervals
                \item   Heart rate
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   ECG features
                        & Decision tree (\SI{85}{\%})                                   \\
        \addlinespace
    Prediction of Paroxysmal AF Onset in Postoperative Patients using Neuro-Fuzzy Modelling
        &   37 patients + 53 controls
            &   30m
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   Number of premature atrial complexes
                \item   HRV: mean, SDRR, rMSSD, total power, LF/HF, entropy
                \item   P-wave duration, amplitude, shape, inflection point, energy ratio
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   ECG features
                        & Neuro-fuzzy (\SI{70}{\%})                                     \\
        \addlinespace
    Alteration of the P-wave non-linear dynamics near the onset of paroxysmal atrial fibrillation
        &   46 patients
            &   2h
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item   P-wave durations
                \item   P-wave area, arc-length
                    \end{itemize}
                    &   Central tendency measurement
                        &   Decision tree (\SI{90}{\%})                                 \\
        \addlinespace
    Role of the P-wave high frequency energy and duration as nonivasive cardiovascular predictors of paroxysmal atrial fibrillation
        &   46 patients + 53 controls
            &   2h
                &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item   P-wave frequency energies
                        \end{itemize}
                        &   Linear regression slope of the variability
                            &   Stepwise discriminant analysis (\SI{80}{\%})                \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \end{table}
    \end{document}
    ```

[image]

Comment: Hello Zarko, many thanks for your help.

I am using a template, so I think I only have to comment the following line: `\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}`. I would like to understand how you specificty the column size?

Comment: @DiogoTec, the best way for understanding is read `tabularx` documentation. shortly. using `X` columns `tabularx` divide table width (belong to `X` columns` on equal parts. this division you can change with `\hsize=x\hsize` where `x`  is factor of increasing (if `x>1`) or decreasing (`y<1`)  by `tabularx` calculated width. those factors i determined experimentally.

Comment: I now understand :) thank you
May I do an extra question? How can I center the table contents both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: @DiogoTec: (i) don't center cell contents, (ii) i don't recommend to center cell contents, (iii) eventually  make exception for column headers (by omitting `thead` options: instead `\thead[lb]{...}` use `\thead{...}`. if you still persist to have (ugly table) with all cells contents centered, than add in preamble `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` and `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}`, and than instead `L` use`C` column specifier, i.e.: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\hsize=1.6\hsize}L >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L c L >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}C @{}}`

Comment: Okay okay. I will follow your suggestion! I would like to adjust the size of the 3rd column, where you specificed `c L`, but when I change it to something like `>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}L` instead, it gives me error. Any idea?

Comment: sum of all factors for changing column width should be integer. why you this for third column? regarding to contents in it is the best to have `c` column type. probably you mean the fourth one. if you will increase its width, you should decrease width of some other column.

Comment: The 3rd column is using too much space. I have added some more rows, which makes the table not fit (vertically) in the entire page...

Comment: width of column is determined by column header. make it narrower, for example use some abbreviation for it and its meaning explain in legend or table notes.

Comment: Alright. Just one last question: with the \usepackage{enumitem} command, my enumerate commands (where I specify the type of bullet points [e.g. `\item[\textbf{Class A:}]`]) changes its output (images bellow). How can I fix this? GOOD: imgur.com/a/sg3v175; BAD: imgur.com/a/Ax9Bnky

Comment: @DiogoTec, sorry, your comment is not clear. if you have new question, please ask it as question. not in comment,